# How can I hide the microsoft banner and script file paths when running a Python script in VS Code's integrated terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm writing basic scripts in VS Code and when I run them the result in the terminal is just..... ugly. Instead of just printing the result of my code, it prints details about my version of Windows, a little copyright notice, the full file path to my code... then eventually gets round to executing my actual code.

Is there any way for me to configure the terminal so that it just shows my code and not all the other bits? I've already seem about an extension called Code Runner, but this prints to the "Output" tab and doesn't allow any user input

Comment: Can u explain how do you run them? Are you refering to debugging?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PowerShell, you can add **"args": ["-NoLogo"],** like this to Hides the copyright banner at startup :

```
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell",
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell": {
      "source": "PowerShell",
      "icon": "terminal-powershell",
      "path": ["C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"],
      "args": ["-NoLogo"],
    }
  },
```

And you also can change the value of `console` in the `launch.json` file. But `internalConsole` does not accept the user input. And `externalTerminal` will prompt a cmd window out of the VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try Jupyter code cells:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py

Answer (score 0):

Try jupyter on visual studio code interface

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow these steps:

1. install python extension for vs code.
   [python extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsWCa.png)
2. After installing reopen vs code and you will see a play button at right-top corner.

   [play button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMenI.png)
3. Click that button and run your code!

Answer (score 0):

- go to settings
- search for terminal
- find `Code-runner : Run in Terminal` and turn that off.